# I need help in designing a database (and signup and login on base of their role )in which there are three user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I want make sign up and login on the base of their role there admin can add users and approved the request of other two user so that they can login.When user click on the sign up the user see sign up page accorading to their roll and same for login .

Answer (score 0):

Django implements a pretty decent authentication framework inside it, so you already have things such as Users, Groups and Permissions to work on. All of those being managed easily by the admin page.

What you want to do is to assign a set of groups/permissions to a newly created user to determine its role and then build a frontend that manages the different kind of users in terms of templates. If you want an user to have itself validated before start using your page, refer to the is_active attribute of the User object.

Read for more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#user-objects